# Регулярные выражения, замена символов

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно убирать из строки ненужные символы методом `replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`.
Например строка `"Hel.l$o wo..rl#d"`
Метасимвол `\\W` убирает все кроме цифровых и буквенных символов. Но мне нужно оставлять в строке еще и пробелы. Как записать выражение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте

```
String result = s.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s]+", "");
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/xNQgyA/1)

Здесь `[^\\w\\s]` — это исключающий символьный класс, который находит 1 и более (благодаря квантификатору `+`) совпадений символов, отличных от цифр/букв/знака `_` и пробельных символов.

Другой способ — исключение пробельных символов из `\W` с помощью "вычитания символьных классов":

```
String result = s.replaceAll("[\\W&&[^\\s]]+", "");
```

Тут шаблон находит все совпадения 1 и более символов, которые находит `\W` *кроме* пробельных символов.

См. [Java-демо](https://ideone.com/CzpiIW).